# neo4j cypher store array property during csv import

Tags: arrays, csv, neo4j, cypher

I need to import data from a csv of the form

```
id;name;targetset
1;"somenode",[1,3,5,8]
2,"someothernode",[3,8]
```

into the graph and I **need to have `targetset` stored as collection (array)** using cypher. I tried

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/mytable.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (:MyNode {id: row.id, name: row.name, targetset: row.targetset});
```

but it stores `targetset` as a string, e.g. `"[1,3,5,8]"`. There does not seem to be a function to convert array-encoding-strings to actual arrays, like there is `toInt` to convert strings to integers. Is there still another possibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) will be your best bet here. Use the function `apoc.convert.fromJsonList()`.

An example of use:

```
WITH "[1,3,5,8]" as arr
RETURN apoc.convert.fromJsonList(arr)
```

Comment: any explanation as to why apoc will be my best bet? simplicity in syntax? speed? i never worked with it

Comment: Just for the sake of query simplicity, in that it most easily fills in the functionality gap and is easy to use and to read.

Comment: @tscherg The main advantage of this solution over my solution is that `apoc.convert.fromJsonList` will return an array of int values. The solution proposed by me will return an array of string values... So I believe that InverseFalcon solution is more apropriated in this case.

Comment: @InverseFalcon tried to integrate APOC locally (win10). maybe I can avoid opening a new question by asking here: in the browser it doesn't show any procedures except `apoc.schema.assert`. remotely it works (debian). any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/mytable.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (:MyNode {id: row.id, name: row.name, targetset: split(substring(row.targetset, 1, length(row.targetset) - 2), ',') });
```

The above code remove the `[` and `]` chars from the string `[1,3,5,8]` using [substring()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-substring) and [length()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-length) functions. After the string `1,3,5,8`is splited considering `,` as separator.